# When would a function be differentiable at the end point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let's say the function is defined on $[x,y]$

I just don't know what to think of here. I think that every function is not differentiable at the end points because they are points! How can the limit exist from the other side of the end point?

More importantly, when would a function be differentiable at the end point?

Can anyone provide an example and explain how he came with it?

Comment: $f(x)=\mathbf{1}_{(x,y)}$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: please flesh that out for me. I am not familiar with the symbols you are using. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: The function equal to one for all points between the points but equal to zero at the end points.

Comment: If it is equal to zero at the end points then the function is not continuous at the end points. I think I need to mention that.

Comment: OK. The answer below is not continuous either. You want something like $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$. Google x sin sin1\x.

Comment: Any luck with at least one answer below?

Comment: How does being CONTINUOUS differ from being just continuous?

Answer (score 3):

For a continuous example take $$f(t) = \sqrt{t-x}+\sqrt{y-t}$$ where the one sided derivatives at the endpoints are infinite.

Comment: thanks a lot! Can you explain the motivation how you formulated it?

Comment: The square root function is one of the simplest examples of a continuous function failing to have a (bounded one-sided) derivative. I just modified it to have two bad points. You should try to build a collection of examples and counterexamples to every mathematical concept you encounter.

Comment: You are right, and that is what I am trying to do. But I did not know that square root function was a common culprit.

Comment: What about $t<y$? You want $y-t$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy It is. (It was the wrong way for a minute or two while I edited the answer to use the OP's bizarre names for the endpoints of the interval.)

Comment: @mrf: you can use anything to label endpoints, right? How is that bizarre?

Comment: @user43901 I agree that 'bizarre' was too strong, but in the context of calculus, $x$ and $y$ are almost universally the independent and dependent variables. To see how strong notational convention is: try differentiating $e^x$ with respect to $e$.

Answer (score 3):

If you can picture the upper half of the unit circle centered at $(0,0)$, try the function $f$ defined by $f(t)=\sqrt{1-t^2}$ for $|t|\leqslant1$ and $f(t)=0$ for $|t|\gt1$.

For the interval $[x,y]$, try $f(t)=\sqrt{(y-t)(t-x)}$ for $x\leqslant t\leqslant y$ and $f(t)=0$ elsewhere, this is the upper half of the circle with diameter $[x,y]\times\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the constant function $1$, it is differentiable over the whole closed interval $[x,y]$.  True, the derivative at the endpoints is one-sided, but that is usually acceptable.  In contrast, the function $$f(z)=\begin {cases} 0 & z=x,y \\ \frac 1{x-z}+\frac 1{y-z} & otherwise \end {cases}$$ is differentiable over $(x,y)$, but not at either endpoint.

Comment: Ah, I never knew that it is usually acceptable that way. Also, would you mind explaining the motivating behind coming up with this function. I am trying to learn how to think about these problems. Thanks

Comment: Not continuous.

Comment: @user43901:  The function is not continuous at the endpoints (it goes off to infinity, but I have defined it to be zero), so there is no derivative.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy:  but the requirement of continuity was not there when I answered.

Comment: Ross is right. That was my mistake.